# Values sent in URL not seen (properties file)

Tags: java, url, parameters, properties, arguments

I have a property file wich contains an url, on the next row the first parameter needed in the url and on the next one, the second one, like this (example):

```
glt.url=http://...?username={0}&password={1}&type=html
glt.username=sew_dw_43
glt.password=RE94ks
```

But when I make the request, I have an error saying:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 85:
```

Still, if I hard-code the values in the url, it works.

Do you have any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you need to encode the parameters before appending it to URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I just replaced the parameters in the Java function which took the strings from the properties file.

It took me a while until I found the function which takes the parameters from the properties file mentioned. Although I don't understand the downvote?! Thank you all for your help!